# Is it possible to set custom ModelBinder for the whole controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a custom model binder and I know two ways of assigning this to my action method:

Either at the method:

```
public ActionResult MyAction([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))] ModelClass filter
```

Or globally in global.asax.cs:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))
```

But I wonder if there is a way to assign the custom model binder on the controller? So it works for all methods in the controller but not globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model binder you have access to the ControllerContext. So it should be easy to bind your model based on the controller information you have available there.

It does smell a bit because you are creating a coupling between your model binding and the controller. But if you use DI to create a strategy pattern and inject a binder resolver into a ModelBinderContainer which then uses its knowledge of your system to choose the desired binding you would have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

No and as far as I know and it does not make much sense logically since a ModelBinder is bound to a Model either globally in the Binders collection (or by adding the attribute directly on the model class) or locally on a model in an action.

However you can still achieve what you want by creating an Aspect (as in from Aspect Oriented Programming) with a tool like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). You will be able to apply that aspect on the Controller level and it will inject the ModelBinder attributes on all methods as a post-compilation step. Question is whether you want to go through all this trouble and more importantly will it bring any value.

An example of an attribute decorator aspect [is available in the PostSharp documentation here](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.0/##PostSharp-2.0.chm/html/fa546b6c-9107-4d5f-b921-b93ead7c42a7.htm).