# Model binder at controller level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Is there a way to implement the following:

```cs
// Model.cs

[ModelBinder(typeof(DefaultModelBinder))]
public class Model
{
}

public class DefaultModelBinder: IModelBinder
{
}

public class CustomModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
}

// Controller1.cs

public class Controller1: Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult Method(Model model)
    {
    }
}

// Controller2.cs

[ModelBinder(typeof(Model), typeof(CustomModelBinder))] // imaginary attribute
public class Controller2: Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult Method(Model model)
    {
    }
}
```

I am aware of the `ModelBinder` at action level, however given a bunch of actions it does not follow DRY principle, as the whole controller is to use the `CustomModelBinder`.

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036511/is-it-possible-to-set-custom-modelbinder-for-the-whole-controller)  help, duplicate ?

Comment: @toby, yes, it looks like that, it is tagged as older MVC 3 though. Also, I don't think the code "smells", since there are many applications where one needs to get essentially the same model object but in a number of ways for various reasons, e.g. different reference IDs for front-end and back-end, client-specific serialization, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
using IModelBinder = System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder;
using ModelBindingContext = System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext;

public class CustomeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the binder can be applied only to action parameters and the model class itself but not to the controller class.

Comment: Just to be sure i understand what you want : a model binder for a specific method and model ?

Comment: I need a model binder applied to a controller rather than to its methods.

Comment: I had a situation where i wrote a custom model binder for a method, but it was called for each of the methods inside the controller. I'm not sure why this happened, but i had to restrict the model binding to only the model i needed. Would this help ? :)

Comment: No, unfortunately. I know my target models and I may need to apply multiple binders at a controller level.